# Building a conditional time series pivot table in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dev_date', 'test_date', 'done_date'])
```

The columns are dates, and represent the date a work item was first accepted into development/test/done in a project (there are a few other columns too, but they aren't important to the question).

I want to build a Cumulative Flow Diagram from this, which is basically an area chart showing, for each day, the total number of items that have been accepted into each stage in the project life cycle.

The most basic algorithm is relatively simple:

1. For each date from the lowest `dev_date` to the highest `done_date`...
2. ... for each column (`dev_date`, `test_date`, `done_date`) ...
3. ... count the number of items where the recorded date is <= the loop date

The output should be something like:

```
date        dev test done
----------  --- ---- ----
2015-01-01  1   0     0
2015-01-02  2   1     0    
2015-01-03  3   2     1
2015-01-04  3   2     1
2015-01-05  4   3     1
2015-01-06  5   3     1
```

Indeed, I could write some fairly naive code to achieve this, looping over dates, then looping over the columns, doing a slice of each series, and a count.

However, it feels like it ought to be possible to do this with `pivot_table()` or some other, more elegant approach (reindexing on the date perhaps and then using `groupBy()`?).

I'm interested in this mostly to get better at Pandas and a little bit because it feels like there is some performance and code quality to be gained.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `value_counts` to count the number of occurrences of each date for each column. For example,

```
In [385]: df['dev_date']
Out[385]: 
0   2000-01-04
1   2000-01-10
2   2000-01-10
3   2000-01-09
4   2000-01-10
5   2000-01-05
6   2000-01-08
7   2000-01-07
8   2000-01-10
9   2000-01-04
Name: dev_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [386]: df['dev_date'].value_counts()
Out[386]: 
2000-01-10    4
2000-01-04    2
2000-01-08    1
2000-01-09    1
2000-01-07    1
2000-01-05    1
Name: dev_date, dtype: int64
```

Then you could use `pd.concat` to concatenate these Series into one DataFrame:

```
In [387]: result = pd.concat({col:df[col].value_counts() for col in df}, axis=1)

In [388]: result
Out[388]: 
            dev_date  test_date  done_date
2000-01-04         2        NaN        NaN
2000-01-05         1        NaN        NaN
2000-01-06       NaN          1        NaN
2000-01-07         1          2        NaN
2000-01-08         1        NaN        NaN
2000-01-09         1        NaN          1
2000-01-10         4        NaN          1
2000-01-11       NaN          2        NaN
2000-01-12       NaN          1        NaN
2000-01-14       NaN        NaN          1
2000-01-15       NaN        NaN          1
2000-01-16       NaN          2        NaN
2000-01-17       NaN          1        NaN
2000-01-18       NaN          1          1
2000-01-20       NaN        NaN          2
2000-01-21       NaN        NaN          1
2000-01-22       NaN        NaN          1
2000-01-24       NaN        NaN          1
```

Replace the NaNs with zeros, and then take the cumulative sum down the rows:

```
result = result.fillna(0).cumsum(axis=0)
```

And finally use `reindex` to make sure every date has a row:

```
start, end = result.index.min(), result.index.max()
result = result.reindex(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'), method='ffill')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate an example df
np.random.seed(2015)
arr = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10,3)).astype(float)
arr[arr == 9] = np.nan
data = np.add.accumulate(
    arr, axis=1).astype('<m8[D]')
data = np.array('2000-01-01 12:34:56', dtype='<M8[ns]') + data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dev_date', 'test_date', 'done_date'])

# strip times from the dates
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.values, dtype='<M8[ns]')
                  .astype('<M8[D]').astype('<M8[ns]'),
                  columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

result = pd.concat({col:df[col].value_counts() for col in df}, axis=1)
result = result.fillna(0).cumsum(axis=0)
start, end = result.index.min(), result.index.max()
result = result.reindex(pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D'), method='ffill')
print(result)
```

yields

```
            dev_date  done_date  test_date
2000-01-04         2          0          0
2000-01-05         3          0          0
2000-01-06         3          0          1
2000-01-07         4          0          3
2000-01-08         5          0          3
2000-01-09         6          1          3
2000-01-10         6          2          3
2000-01-11         6          2          4
2000-01-12         6          2          4
2000-01-13         6          2          4
2000-01-14         6          3          4
```

---

In the OP's actual problem the DataFrame has columns containing both
`datetime.datetime` and None values. These can 
be converted to a DataFrame with `datetime64[ns]` using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.values, dtype='<M8[ns]'),
                  columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

To also strip out the time part of the datetimes, you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.values, dtype='<M8[ns]')
                  .astype('<M8[D]').astype('<M8[ns]'),
                  columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Comment: Brilliantly! What does the <m8[D] bit mean?

Comment: The string `'<m8[D]'` specifies the [`timedelta64[D]` NumPy dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) when passed to the [`astype` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html). The `[D]` indicates this dtype has units of days. '<M8[D]' -- notice the `M` is capitalized -- specifies the `datetime64[D]` NumPy dtype. `timedelta64[D]`s [can be added](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) to `datetime64[D]`s. I used it above to convert random ints into random dates.

Comment: Cool ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two problems when I try to do this: (1) My source data frame contains datetime64s and I'm struggling to strip the time information from them; and (2) when I run it the series name is lost so the columns in the final data frame has names 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: Regarding (1): Do you want to strip off the times *before* the `value_counts` is called, or merely off of `result.index`? Regarding (2): I'm not sure why this is happening to you; it doesn't happen in the example I posted.

Comment: 1: I suppose it doesn't matter, but if two dates are on the same day they'd need to be summed. So I guess before. 2: I pasted your code verbatim and get numeric columns. Series names are lost when value_counts is called.

Comment: (1) `df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.astype('<M8[D]'), columns=df.columns)` can be used to strip the times off of the datetime64s. (2) If the list comprehension is changed to a dict comprehension: `{col:df[col].value_counts() for col in df}`, then `pd.concat` will definitely return a DataFrame with the keys as column names. Perhaps a difference in Pandas version explains the difference in behavior we are seeing. I'm using 0.16.2. I've edited the post above to include these changes.

Comment: Strange, I'm also on 0.16.2. With the new code, I'm getting an error on the `astype()` call: `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: -12626367463881308-09-18 00:00:00`.

Comment: I think the timestamp may be caused by a `None` value. If I do a `dropna()` I'm now getting `Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'`.

Comment: Okay, I was able to reproduce the problem in my toy example by using `df.iloc[::2, 0] = np.nan` to add some NaT values to one of the columns. This can be fixed by using `df.values.astype('<M8[D]').astype('<M8[ns]')` to strip the times from the dates *and* convert the data back to `datetime64[ns]` (instead of `datetime64[D]`) dtype. I've edited the post to include this change.

Comment: That removed the error, but something is still different. After the double `astype()`, the dates are cast to something strange, they are now things like `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000` and `1782-12-28 04:47:51.815667712`. I suspect the reason is that my data is generated by querying an API that returns Python datetime objects, and your randomly generated data is using datetime64s from numpy? By the way, thanks for all your help - I'm really grateful!

Comment: Given `datetime.datetime` values in the columns, you could strip off the times using 
`df[col] = df[col].dt.date`. This attempts to convert the column's values to `datetime.date`s.

Comment: If this does not work, it would be very helpful to have a sample of your actual `df`. Using `df.head().to_dict('list')` to generate a small example which exhibits the problem is one way to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85348/discussion-between-optilude-and-unutbu).

Comment: I think we got there :) The latest example works. Thank you *so* much!